# Show an alert for a not existing file on sdcard in android

Tags: android

The following code works properly and plays music files on the sd card.
I want show an alert if a music file does not exist on the sdcard ("not existing music file").
What should I write for this?

please help me

this is my code:

```
public class DoaMatn1 extends Activity {

 MediaPlayer player;
 SeekBar seek_bar;
 Handler seekHandler = new Handler();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.doamatn);

    WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvdoa);
    wv.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
    wv.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/doatavasol.html");
WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
webSettings.setDefaultFontSize(20);
 getInit();
    seekUpdation();
}   
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File audioFile = new File(sdcard.getPath() + "/bluetooth/یه سوال دارم مگه.mp3");

 public void getInit() {
     seek_bar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sbdoa);
     player = MediaPlayer.create(this,Uri.fromFile(audioFile));
seek_bar.setMax(player.getDuration());
final ImageButton ib =(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnplaydoa);
ib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // check for already playing
            if(player.isPlaying()){
                if(player!=null){
                    player.pause();
                    // Changing button image to play button
                    ib.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                }
            }else{
                // Resume song
                if(player!=null){
                    player.start();
                    // Changing button image to pause button
                    ib.setImageResource(R.drawable.puse);
                }   
            }

        }

    });

 }
 Runnable run = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            seekUpdation();
        }
    };

    public void seekUpdation() {

        seek_bar.setProgress(player.getCurrentPosition());
        seekHandler.postDelayed(run, 1000);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(player!=null){
            if(player.isPlaying()){
         player.stop();
       }
       super.onBackPressed();
    }
}}
```

---

my logcat:

```
 02-09 00:57:24.629: E/AndroidRuntime(3650): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 02-09 00:57:24.629: E/AndroidRuntime(3650): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.aseman14.ertebatbakhoda/com.aseman14.ertebatbakhoda.matn.DoaMatn1}: java.lang.NullPointerException
 02-09 00:57:24.629: E/AndroidRuntime(3650):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
 02-09 00:57:24.629: E/AndroidRuntime(3650):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
 02-09 00:57:24.629: E/AndroidRuntime(3650):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
 02-09 00:57:24.629: E/AndroidRuntime(3650):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
 02-09 00:57:24.629: E/AndroidRuntime(3650):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 02-09 00:57:24.629: E/AndroidRuntime(3650):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
 02-09 00:57:24.629: E/AndroidRuntime(3650):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
 02-09 00:57:24.629: E/AndroidRuntime(3650):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 02-09 00:57:24.629: E/AndroidRuntime(3650):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
 02-09 00:57:24.629: E/AndroidRuntime(3650):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
 02-09 00:57:24.629: E/AndroidRuntime(3650):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
 02-09 00:57:24.629: E/AndroidRuntime(3650):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 02-09 00:57:24.629: E/AndroidRuntime(3650): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 02-09 00:57:24.629: E/AndroidRuntime(3650):    at com.aseman14.ertebatbakhoda.matn.DoaMatn1.getInit(DoaMatn1.java:49)
 02-09 00:57:24.629: E/AndroidRuntime(3650):    at com.aseman14.ertebatbakhoda.matn.DoaMatn1.onCreate(DoaMatn1.java:39)
 02-09 00:57:24.629: E/AndroidRuntime(3650):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
 02-09 00:57:24.629: E/AndroidRuntime(3650):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
 02-09 00:57:24.629: E/AndroidRuntime(3650):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: @user2469133 There is no need to do this, and knowingly using an exception to control program flow is a terrible suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void getInit() {
    ...
    if (!audioFile.exists()){
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Music doesn't exist");
        alertDialog.setMessage("The music file was not found");
        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                 // handle click here
            }
        });
        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
        alertDialog.show();
    }
    ...
```

Comment: I am add above code but can not be entered to activity and force closed

Comment: Please try to explain that more detailed.

Comment: I am add my log cat below

Comment: Your crash is not related to my answer. Have a look at line 49 of DoaMatn1.java. An object you use there is empty. I'd recommend debugging that. Google `debug Android app` if you don't know how to do that.